# Accepted answer does not always appear at the top

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, sorting, self-answer

I just recognised that an accepted answer does not always appear first, at the top of the other answers (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513871/fluent-nhibernate-and-dynamicupdate)).

Sometimes it does, but if I reload the page the two answers change their positions and the accepted answer is at the bottom.

Comment: From the linked question: *"You can accept your own answer to a question. There is no reputation awarded and the answer does not float to the top of the list."*

Comment: Question was closed as dupe then re-opened, so we lost the "linked question"; I pointed to [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because the OP accepted their own answer.  That's the exception to the rule that the accepted answer always appears at the top.  When someone accepts their own answer, the software allows more highly voted answers from other people to outrank the accepted answer.  In the case of a tie, the accepted answer is ranked randomly among tied answers.

Answer (score 6):

When an OP accepts his own answer as correct, it is not sorted at the top.

At that time the normal sorting applies, which displays equally-scoring posts in random order.

In other words, this is not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) but a feature; [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).